# dynamically loaded div content using ajax has further links to different files. How to load the content of these links in the same div

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dynamic, loading

Problem statement:
I have a page (main.jsp) with a header, left panel and content divs. When I click on any link in the left panel I use a javascript ajax call to load the content in the  div. So far so good. Now this newly loaded content is actually page one of three of an input form. So this form1 has a submit button that posts data to a servlet which in turn forwards a jsp as a view. This view is nothing but form2 of three.

Now I want this form2 to also load in the same div. As of now when i click on next the form2 opens a new page rather than opening in the parent page's  div.

I dont want to use frames. How do I achieve this? is there a way to call the ajax function in main.jsp from form1,2,3 etc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery load function

```
$("#your_content_div_id").load("external_file.jsp");
```

Comment: Hi Miqdad, you are loading a static jsp page. form1 is a different page altogether, it does not have access to the div on the main page